# Assigning IP from Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, set, ip, windows-xp, nic

With the below code I am getting an error "Invalid interface LAN: specified".  This code works in Win7, however, does NOT working in windows XP.  I suspect it has something to do with the "!adapterName!" conflicting within XP.

I utilize this script to obtain the NIC Name in case it changes in the future some how and would like to keep this scheme.  Any ideas how I can continue with such script in an XP environment?

```
    :: Set primary and alternate DNS for IPv4
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=* delims=0" %%a in ("%SITEID%") DO set DROPZERO=%%a
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET adapterName=

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%a IN ('IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"') DO SET adapterName=%%a

REM Removes "Ethernet adapter" from the front of the adapter name
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
REM Removes the colon from the end of the adapter name
SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!

echo Setting Static IP Information... 
set IP_Addr=10.102.%DROPZERO%.105
set D_Gate=10.102.%DROPZERO%.1
set Sub_Mask=255.255.255.0
netsh interface ip set address "!adapterName!" static %IP_Addr% %Sub_Mask% %D_Gate% 1 > output_net.txt
netsh interface ip set dns name="!adapterName!" static 10.98.1.26 primary >> output_net.txt
netsh interface ip add dns name="!adapterName!" 10.98.1.48 index=2 >> output_net.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps the format of `ipconfig` output differs from Windows 7 to XP. Take a look at the output of `IPCONFIG ^| FIND /I "ETHERNET ADAPTER"` in Windows 7 then in XP. If the format is different then your for loop may not set the `adapterName` correctly.

Comment: I broke it down as you suggested and it is setting adaptername correctly.

Comment: Replace your `netsh` calls with `echo netsh` and see if the commands are what you think they are.

Comment: Mark, thank you! This brought my eyes to where they needed to be.  
This line of code SET "adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!" ACTUALLY NEEDS to be "adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-2!" NOTE THE 2.  Removes the colon from the end of the adapter name. -1 worked in Win7, -2 needed in this scenario. I had verified the name of the NIC and there is no extra space at the end either.

Comment: Since you found the solution, can you please post it and mark it as the Answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of the batch code posted by [T-Diddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3380038/t-diddy) which works on English and German Windows.

```dos
@echo off
rem Set primary and alternate DNS for IPv4.
setlocal
set "SITEID=020"

rem The next line removes leading zeros to define the third octet of the
rem IPv4 address always correct. There are implementations on IP address
rem parsing routines on Windows (for example command ping) and Linux which
rem interpret integer numbers with a leading 0 as octal number and not as
rem decimal number according to C standard. The number 020 would be set
rem unexpected as decimal number 16 instead of 20.
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A in ("%SITEID%") do set DROPZERO=%%A

rem Get first ethernet adapter name output by command IPCONFIG filtered
rem by command FINDSTR with a case-insensitive regular expression search.
rem "Ethernet adapter " is output left to the name of the adapter on English
rem Windows. But on German Windows "Ethernetadapter" is the right word. This
rem is the reason for the regular expression with an optional space between
rem "ethernet" and "adpater".
set "AdapterName="
for /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "ethernet.*adapter"') do (
    set "AdapterName=%%A"
    goto SetAddress
)
rem No ethernet adapter found, exit batch job.
endlocal
goto :EOF

:SetAddress
rem Remove everything from beginning of string to first occurrence of
rem the string "adapter " to remove "Ethernet adapter " respectively
rem on German Windows "Ethernetadapter".
set "AdapterName=%AdapterName:*adapter =%"

rem Remove the colon from the end of the adapter name.
set "AdapterName=%AdapterName:~0,-1%"

echo Ethernet adapter found: %AdapterName%
echo Setting static IP information ...
set IpAddress=10.102.%DROPZERO%.105
set DefaultGate=10.102.%DROPZERO%.1
set SubNetMask=255.255.255.0
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip set address "%adapterName%" static %IpAddress% %SubNetMask% %DefaultGate% ^1>output_net.txt
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip set dns name="%adapterName%" static 10.98.1.26 primary>>output_net.txt
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe interface ip add dns name="%adapterName%" 10.98.1.48 index=^2>>output_net.txt
endlocal
```

I don't see here a problem on Windows XP on using

```
set "AdapterName=%AdapterName:~0,-1%"
```

But in the `for` loop the command `findstr` is used instead of `find`. And double quotes are used on setting the adapter name to avoid that by mistake a trailing space is appended to the name of the adapter. That could be the important difference.

**A general note for everybody reading this answer:**

Never enter the 4 octets of an IPv4 address with 1 or 2 leading zeros. That could very easily result in being interpreted as octal number which is definitely not expected by anybody.

You don't believe that. Try it out on Linux or Windows for example on running the command

```
ping 192.168.050.020
```

Do you have expected that ping is executed with 192.168.40.16 as written in output?