# How to save values of variables to file and load them back from file?

Tags: batch-file

So far I have a batch script that changes an IP address to a static address. Right now the variables are defined in the batch file.

What I'm looking for is adding an `IF` statement that checks if a file does not exist with the values for the variables in which case the batch file asks for the values of the variables and then saves the variables' values to file to use later again on setting IP address.

So far I have this:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET IPAddress=10.10.3.5
SET Subnet=255.255.0.0
SET Gateway=10.10.1.1
SET Dns=10.10.11.87
@ECHO IP Address will now change to the static address of "%IPAddress%"
netsh int ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static address="%IPAddress%" mask="%Subnet%"  gateway="%Gateway%"
@ECHO IP Address Changed...
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul
@ECHO Subnet Changed...
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul
@ECHO Gateway Changed...
timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK > nul
@ECHO DNS Changed...
netsh int ip set dnsservers name="Local Area Connection" source=static address="%Dns%" validate=no

@Echo IP address is now changed.  You can now close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37106858/2152082)

Comment: if you've set `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning then the `@` before each `echo` is completely redundant

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you re-invent which exists already dozens of times. Search with a world wide web search engine for `switch network settings` and you find lots of tools for switching between network settings for a network interface.

It is also possible to set multiple IP addresses, subnet masks, gateways and DNS servers on a network interface making it not necessary to switch the network settings all the time when using always the same networks like office network and home network.

However, here is a simple batch code for loading and saving values of environment variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "SaveData="
set "IpMod_IPAddress="
set "IpMod_Subnet="
set "IpMod_Gateway="
set "IpMod_Dns="

if exist "IpMod_Data.txt" for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=_=" %%A in ("IpMod_Data.txt") do if "%%A" == "IpMod" set "%%A_%%B=%%C"

if not "!IpMod_IPAddress!" == "" goto ValidateIpAddress

:InputIpAddress
echo/
set "SaveData=1"
set "IpMod_IPAddress=10.10.3.5"
set /P "IpMod_IPAddress=Enter IP address (default: %IpMod_IPAddress%): "

:ValidateIpAddress
rem Add here extra code to validate the user input using delayed
rem expansion with execution of goto InputIpAddress on invalid input.

if not "!IpMod_Subnet!" == "" goto ValidateSubnet

:InputSubnet
echo/
set "SaveData=1"
set "IpMod_Subnet=255.255.0.0"
set /P "IpMod_Subnet=Enter subnet mask (default: %IpMod_Subnet%): "

:ValidateSubnet
rem Add here extra code to validate the user input using delayed
rem expansion with execution of goto InputSubnet on invalid input.

if not "!IpMod_Gateway!" == "" goto ValidateGateway

:InputGateway
echo/
set "SaveData=1"
set "IpMod_Gateway=10.10.1.1"
set /P "IpMod_Gateway=Enter gateway IP (default: %IpMod_Gateway%): "

:ValidateGateway
rem Add here extra code to validate the user input using delayed
rem expansion with execution of goto InputGateway on invalid input.

if not "!IpMod_Dns!" == "" goto ValidateDns

:InputDns
echo/
set "SaveData=1"
set "IpMod_Dns=10.10.1.1"
set /P "IpMod_Dns=Enter DNS IP (default: %IpMod_Dns%): "

:ValidateDns
rem Add here extra code to validate the user input using delayed
rem expansion with execution of goto InputDns on invalid input.

if "%SaveData%" == "1" set IpMod_ >"IpMod_Data.txt"

echo/
echo The network data are:
echo/
echo IP address:  !IpMod_IPAddress!
echo Subnet mask: !IpMod_Subnet!
echo Gateway IP:  !IpMod_Gateway!
echo DNS IP:      !IpMod_Dns!

echo IP Address will now change to the static address of "%IpMod_IPAddress%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe int ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static address="%IpMod_IPAddress%" mask="%IpMod_Subnet%" gateway="%IpMod_Gateway%"
echo IP Address Changed...
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NOBREAK >nul
echo Subnet Changed...
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NOBREAK >nul
echo Gateway Changed...
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NOBREAK >nul
echo Dns Changed...
%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe int ip set dnsservers name="Local Area Connection" source=static address="%IpMod_Dns%" validate=no

echo IP address is now changed.  You can now close this window.
endlocal
pause >nul
```

What I know from C++ code I wrote for my company to check network settings entered by users to detect invalid input as much as possible I would assume you have 0.5% of entire task done with this code. Good luck on coding the remaining 99.5%.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `timeout /?`
- `netsh /?`
- `netsh int /?`
- `netsh int ip /?`
- `netsh int ipv4 /?`
- and so on for `netsh`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).
And take also a look on answer on [Assigning IP from batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26078195/3074564).